# Dismiss View Controller within UITabController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

I have the following stack on my Storyboard

```
-> Navigation Controller 
 -> MyCoursesViewController (does a prepareForSegue to next 'view')
  -> Course Info UITabController (I select Setting Tab)
   -> Setting Navigation Controller
    -> SettingViewController
```

When I am in the Setting Tab: SettingViewController, I have a UIButton which says ‘Exit Course’ and I want it to go back to MyCoursesViewController. How can I pop to reach this view controller?

I tried the things below:

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

but to no avail.

Is there a way to simply dismiss or do I need to implement a delegate from MyCoursesViewController to pass to the SettingViewController via the UITabController? I am not sure how to pass a delegate to `MyCourses -> Course Info Tab -> Setting`. If it was `MyCourses -> Setting`, that’s just a simple delegate pass from class to class but the confusing part is the intermediate Tab controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it sound like `MyCoursesViewController` is the `rootViewController` of your `NavigationController`.

You pushed the `CourseInfoUITabController` to your stack and your `SettingViewController` is actually embedded in a `UINavigationController` therefore you can do this:

`self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`

Comment: I updated the question, so to answer your question, yes the MyCoursesViewController is the rootViewController of the NavigationController. I performForSegue to CourseInfoUITabController. I tried both pops but it's not doing popping.

Comment: what is the `style` you set for the `segue`? If you set it up in storyboard, you can see the `style` when you are setting the `identifier` of the `segue`

Comment: its just a Show (Push)

Comment: I just setup a simple project like what you describe above and `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` works. Do you have any warning message in the log as your are transiting?

Comment: apologies, I missed one level which is a NavigationController when the setting tab is selected. Hit 'Setting' tab -> navigation controller -> setting uiviewcontroller

Comment: I have updated my answer. This should work for you: `self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`.

Comment: It still doesn't work, something is still not correct. Even from a custom control that extends UITabBarController, I'm trying to pop back to MyCourses, it doesn't do anything but sit on the same screen.

Comment: finally got it to work, there were issues with the uitabbarcontroller but now its resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

I think that to go from `MyCoursesViewController` to your `UITabController` you're using pushViewController or a segue's doing it for you, so to go back you must use `popViewControllerAnimated`.

`dismissViewControllerAnimated` is used to dismiss viewcontroller shown using `presentViewController`

Edit:

so if you have two UINavigationController I think this code will work for you:

```
self.navigationController?.parentViewController?.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: ops I tried that too but didn't include it on the list

Comment: replace all "?" with "!" and see which lines lines passes and those who crashes the app, I think all the line starting with self.navigationController!. will crash because SettingViewController is not directly attached to a uinavigationController

Comment: This made me think and having looked at the hierarchy it does have a UINavigationController before the SettingViewController. So I need something like a double pop.

Comment: it seems like I can't pop the UITabBarController

Comment: I also got this approach to work as well after updating the UITabBarController class.

Answer (score 1):

You can emit custom NSNotification from SettingViewController, which will be processed by MyCoursesViewController and do whatever you need.

This approach is more correct as during development things might become more complicated and your hierarchy might change. By using NSNotification you make your parts of code less coupled, which is a good thing

Comment: how would you pass down the View down to MyCoursesViewController to dismiss/pop?

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion and if i understand your view hierarchy correctly it should simply be:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let rootNavigationController = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
rootNavigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```